# Automatically replace members with an empty user role with another role

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-roles

I want to move all members whose user role is empty to the default role. Is there a code about it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, first you can use `wp_get_users_with_no_role()` [function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_users_with_no_role/) to get all users with no role (This function returns user ids). Then you can pass that user_id `$u = new WP_User( $user_id );` and set the new role `$u->set_role( 'subscriber' );`. Here you can also find list of user [Roles and Capabilities](https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/).

Paste that in your theme `functions.php` file.

```
add_action('init', function(){
    $users = wp_get_users_with_no_role();
    if( !empty($users) ){
        foreach($users as $user_id) {
            $u = new WP_User( $user_id );
            $u->set_role( 'subscriber' );
        }
    }
}, 10);
```

*This code isn't tested so let us know if that worked!*

Comment: very good it really worked thank you very much my friend. :) :)